# How to get a marquee effect in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new to android development and I am trying to make a textview scroll horizontally across the screen_activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<TextView
        android:text="Single-line text view that scrolls automatically if the text is too long to fit in the widget" 
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Then, try findViewById(R.id.tv).setSelected(true);